# listdata.svc and custom field types

Tags: custom-field-types, listdata.svc

I have a custom SharePoint field, that inherits from SPFieldMultiColumn (always a SPFieldMultiColumt(2)).

When I add this field to a SharePoint list it works good. But I can't see that field in the listdata.svc service.

Is there some additional config needed or are custom Field Types not suppoerted in ListData.svc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all fields are returned by listdata.svc. Take for example fields that are publishing related like Page Content. In your case it might be that the SPMultiColumn field is a non sortable field in SQL database meaning that derived types are not sortable as well. Have a look at my post about missing fields from Listdata at [Push or pull pages from SP2010 using listdata.svc](http://hermansberghem.blogspot.com/2010/07/push-or-pull-publishing-pages-from.html)

Comment: Thanx. I guess it's either CMIS or back to managed client object model :)

Comment: As far as I have discovered CMIS does not support publishing at this moment. ;-)

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have a field created from a custom field type. The custom field type is based on SPFieldLookup. That field is not shown in the ListData.svc. Is there a way to fix this or is it not supported.

Comment: @Sarath Unfortunately not. Client Object Model would be better way to go.